# Visual Studio Build for windowsphone error : (XapDeployCmd.exe) didn't found

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, xap

I build and emulate my cordova app in android device and VisualStudio Android Emulator successfully in Visual Studio.

But when I try to build and deploy my app to windowsphone device I got this error that said the file "XapDeployCmd.exe" does not in %PATH%

> ERROR: Error executing ""XapDeployCmd" /enumeratedevices": 
>   '"XapDeployCmd"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   WARNING: XapDeploy tool (XapDeployCmd.exe) didn't found. Assume that it's in
>    %PATH% and deploy fails.

When I referred to the path that I must find the file "XapDeployCmd.exe" in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\XAP Deployment" I saw there is one file there: "XapDeploy.exe" and "XapDeployCmd.exe" is not there

so where is "XapDeployCmd.exe" ?
I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community With Update 3 and I installed Windows Phone SDK 8.0

Comment: Try reinstalling the Windows Phone SDK 8.0.

Comment: I don't think reinstalling Windows Phone SDK 8.0 can solve the problem.
Because I have exactly same problem (and same software versions installed) in my work pc  : XapDeployCmd.exe is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Tools for Apache Cordova only supports deploying to Windows devices 8.1.

To deploy to Windows 8, you need Visual Studio 2013 which has a completely different project structure, and I don't recommend using it.

Most users who are on a version of Windows 8 tend to be on version 8.1

Answer (score 0):

As I stated before، I had installed Windows Phone SDK 8.0 .
with installing Windows Phone SDK 8.0 , Visual Studio 2012 will be installed.

But the file "XapDeployCmd.exe" is not with this version of visual studio.
Installing Update 5 (update 2 or later) of visual studio 2012 will install "XapDeployCmd.exe" with itself. [Visual Studio 2012 Iso](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=623359) and problem will be solved.

after solving this problem if you encounter with error like 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x89721800' , refer to [this article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/796ea925-c1bf-4fb3-bc67-4967823b51eb/exception-from-hresult-0x89721800-when-deploying-windows-phone-in-visual-studio-2012?forum=wptools)